# How should a REST API deal with creating an object with non-fatal errors?

Tags: api, rest

I have a Foo REST Controller that supports POST to '/foo' to create a new foo object.

For simplicity let's say that the User object only has a nickname field.

The server currently does various validations that ensure that the foo can be saved. (e.g. Logged in user has access or username contains no invalid characters) If the new foo cannot be created an error code in the 400's is returned with a list of error messages.

However, I would like to be able to warn users of the api that the nickname may not work in the way they expected. (e.g. They already have a foo with that nickname or that nickname will not work if used with one of our legacy features.)

I definitely don't want to completely prevent them from creating a foo with such a nickname but they should know about the potential issue and have a chance to go back if they choose.

I see three ways to deal with this:

1. Add a '/foo/validate' endpoint that allows a POST (or potentially PUT) of the foo they are hoping to make. This endpoint would return any fatal and non-errors in a way that allows them to tell the difference. If there are no fatal errors they would know that a POST to '/foo' would successfully create a new object since '/foo' does not perform validation for non-fatal errors.
2. Add a parameter to the foo object like 'force.' If a user performs a POST to '/foo' without 'force' set to true, the server will abort saving the new instance for both fatal and non-fatal errors. If the user noticed that only non-fatal errors were returned, they could set 'force' to true and try again. This time, non-fatal errors would be ignored and the new foo would be created.
3. If the user performs a POST with an object that has only non-fatal errors, the server creates the new foo and in the response body there would be a list of these errors (and a non-201 status code?). The user could then decide whether they wanted to a) leave the object as-is b) update the new foo to avoid the warnings, or c) DELETE the foo.

I realize that any of these would work but, I'm wondering which approach fits best with web standards. Now that I typed them out, I'm thinking that 3 is probably the closest although I'm not sure what status code to return for an object that was created (201) but was not perfectly 'successful.'

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider using the [prefer header](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-snell-http-prefer-18#page-12) "handling=strict" or "handling=lenient" processing option to allow the client to choose how they want to proceed.

If the user chooses handling=lenient and you detect non-fatal errors then return a 201 but also return a [http-problem](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-problem-05) body describing the errors detected.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to support resources with non-fatal errors, then use option 3. The status code should be `201` as the resource was created. This is regardless of any issues it might have. Include details of the issues in the response and the hypermedia controls for the client to resolve the issues.

However, do you really want to allow the create to succeed even though you know they will could be impacted by the "potential issue"? Sounds like a world of hurt down the line. Personally I would keep the POST to `/foo` and if validation fails, respond with a `409 Conflict` status code along with the reasons why it failed.